# Is it possible to tell whether a set of functions is equicontinuous from the graph of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, intuition

I never internalized why the set of functions $f_n(x) = \sin(nx)$ is not equicontinuous

I know I can show that it is not equicontinuous by definition, by choice of appropriate $x,y$ for $|x-y|<\delta$. But I do not quite understand this by examining the graph of $\sin(nx)$.

I also cannot say whether $\sin(nx)$ is or isn't equicontinuous immediately just by looking at the function $\sin(nx)$.

Can someone who is knowledgable on this topic demonstrate how exactly you can tell from the graph of a set of functions whether such set is or is not equicontinuous?

Comment: They get arbitrarily steep.

Comment: The main reason we cannot tell "from the graph of the function" is that we are dealing with a set of functions (likely an infinite set, in the interesting case).

Comment: @T.Bongers I had a feeling that was the case, but I couldn't produce any examples aside from $x^n$....Could you produce an example that contrasts between equicontinuity and nonequicontinuity?